# Mediawiki dies with FileBackendException: 'Backend with name `shared-backend` already registered'

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to setup Mediawiki. I have confirmed that i am able to load Special pages (any of them), but when it comes to the regular pages the site dies with the following:

```
Exception encountered, of type "FileBackendException"
[32b52f48] /Main_Page FileBackendException from line 125 of /......../mediawiki/includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php: Backend with name `shared-backend` already registered.
Backtrace:
#0 /......../mediawiki/includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php(109): FileBackendGroup->register(array)
#1 /......../mediawiki/includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php(47): FileBackendGroup->initFromGlobals()
#2 /......../mediawiki/includes/filerepo/FileRepo.php(152): FileBackendGroup::singleton()
#3 /......../mediawiki/includes/filerepo/LocalRepo.php(54): FileRepo->__construct(array)
#4 /......../mediawiki/includes/filerepo/RepoGroup.php(418): LocalRepo->__construct(array)
#5 /......../mediawiki/includes/filerepo/RepoGroup.php(403): RepoGroup->newRepo(array)
#6 /......../mediawiki/includes/filerepo/RepoGroup.php(228): RepoGroup->initialiseRepos()
#7 /......../mediawiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(4079): RepoGroup->checkRedirect(Title)
#8 /......../mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(2247): wfIsBadImage(string, Title)
#9 /......../mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(2013): Parser->replaceInternalLinks2(string)
#10 /......../mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(1262): Parser->replaceInternalLinks(string)
#11 /......../mediawiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(439): Parser->internalParse(string)
#12 /......../mediawiki/includes/content/WikitextContent.php(331): Parser->parse(string, Title, ParserOptions, boolean, boolean, integer)
#13 /......../mediawiki/includes/content/AbstractContent.php(497): WikitextContent->fillParserOutput(Title, integer, ParserOptions, boolean, ParserOutput)
#14 /......../mediawiki/includes/poolcounter/PoolWorkArticleView.php(140): AbstractContent->getParserOutput(Title, integer, ParserOptions)
#15 /......../mediawiki/includes/poolcounter/PoolCounterWork.php(123): PoolWorkArticleView->doWork()
#16 /......../mediawiki/includes/page/Article.php(676): PoolCounterWork->execute()
#17 /......../mediawiki/includes/actions/ViewAction.php(44): Article->view()
#18 /......../mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(490): ViewAction->show()
#19 /......../mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(287): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#20 /......../mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(714): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#21 /......../mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(508): MediaWiki->main()
#22 /......../mediawiki/index.php(41): MediaWiki->run()
#23 {main}
```

Unfortunately there is no documentation that i can find anywhere that deals with this exception apart from [this](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classFileBackendException.html#details) which isn't of much use.

I have tried disabling all of the extensions, thinking that some of them may be at fault, generating some object that needs to remain as a singleton, but that didn't help.

`$wgFileBackends` is only defined once in `DefaultSettings.php`.

```
# grep -R 'wgFileBackends' .
./includes/DefaultSettings.php: * The name "local-fs" should correspond by name to an entry in $wgFileBackends.
./includes/DefaultSettings.php: * @see $wgFileBackends
./includes/DefaultSettings.php: *   - backend          A file backend name (see $wgFileBackends).
./includes/DefaultSettings.php:$wgFileBackends = array();
./includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php:            global $wgLocalFileRepo, $wgForeignFileRepos, $wgFileBackends;
./includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php:            $this->register( $wgFileBackends );
./includes/filebackend/README:$wgFileBackends. To access one of those defined backends, one would use
./includes/externalstore/ExternalStoreMwstore.php: * The file backends must be defined in $wgFileBackends and must be global
./tests/phpunit/includes/filebackend/FileBackendTest.php:               global $wgFileBackends;
./tests/phpunit/includes/filebackend/FileBackendTest.php:                               foreach ( $wgFileBackends as $conf ) {
./tests/phpunit/includes/filerepo/StoreBatchTest.php:           global $wgFileBackends;
./tests/phpunit/includes/filerepo/StoreBatchTest.php:                   foreach ( $wgFileBackends as $conf ) {
./tests/phpunit/includes/parser/NewParserTest.php:              global $wgFileBackends;
./tests/phpunit/includes/parser/NewParserTest.php:                              foreach ( $wgFileBackends as $conf ) {
```

Comment: File backend configuration is in [`$wgFileBackends`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileBackends); see if it has duplicates.

Comment: @Tgr That sounded like a promising lead, but as you can see in the updated question it's only defined once, and in DefaultSettings.php at that.

Comment: I mean, see if it contains duplicates (two arrays with the same `name` key). Stuff might get added dynamically, so you should probably just it just before `MediaWiki::run()` in `index.php`.

Comment: Also, [`$wgForeignFileRepos`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgForeignFileRepos) can auto-register backends via the (apparently undocumented :/ ) `backend` key. That should not cause conflicts but I think in old versions of MediaWiki it could (the related bug was [T114810](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T114810)).

Comment: There are *three* `shared-backend` keys. I guess i'll be looking for something that does that.

Comment: @Tgr Thank you! It was $wgForeignFileRepos. If you want to write an answer, i'll accept it. Otherwise i'll write a self-answer to help others who might be looking for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323407/tgr)'s comments i was able to figure out the answer.

The problem was the [$wgForeignFileRepos](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgForeignFileRepos) array that was defined in the `LocalSettings.php`. It was left from the previous version of Mediawiki, where apparently same names were not the problem.

It is essential that the names given to the cells is different and none can be titled 'shared'. This point is actually made on the [$wgForeignFileRepos](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgForeignFileRepos) documentation page:

```
$wgForeignFileRepos[] = array(
   'class'                   => 'ForeignAPIRepo',
   'name'                    => 'commonswiki', // Must be a distinct name
   'apibase'                 => 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php',
   'hashLevels'              => 2,
   ...
   );
```